# Check updation and send mail

Tags: sas

I using index to avoid duplicates everytime dataset gets updated and send mail according its failure and success. Below is the code.

```
data lib.new(index =(dual=(name date)/ unique));
set lib.old;
run;

options emailsys=smtp;
%macro sendmail;
%if &syserr ne 0 %then %do;
data _null_;
filename mailbox EMAIL 'abc@gmail.com' subject ='Failed';
file mailbox;
put "Data already avaialable. Please submit for different";
run; %end;
%else %do; data _null_;
filename mailbox EMAIL 'abc@gmail.com' subject ='Success';
file mailbox;
put "Data created"; run; %end;
%mend sendmail;
%sendmail;
```

when I run above code. I can receive mail whenever data update is success. But when I am not receiving mail when it fails

Is there any other way to do.

For success. I am getting below log with email details and mail triggered.

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSERR resolves to 0
MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   data _null_;
MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   filename mailbox EMAIL 'abc@gmail.com'   subject   'Success';
MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   file mailbox;
MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   put "Data created";
MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   run;

NOTE: The file MAILBOX is:
  E-Mail Access Device

Message sent
  To:          "abc@gmail.com"
  The SAS System

  Cc:          
  Bcc:         
  Subject:     Job Success
  Attachments: 
  NOTE: 1 record was written to the file MAILBOX.
```

For failure. I am getting below log and mail not triggered

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSERR resolves to 1012
MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   data _null_;
MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   filename mailbox EMAIL 'abc@gmail.com' subject ='Job Failed';
MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   file mailbox;
 The SAS System

MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):   put "Data already available. Please submit for different";
```

MACROGEN(SENDMAIL):  run;

Comment: It worked perfectly for me, I received emails on both events. Check the email Id that you are putting in the first instance . i.e when the code fails

Comment: I have updated the question with log details

Comment: I got the same log but with following
"SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSERR resolves to 1012
MLOGIC(SENDMAIL):  %IF condition &syserr ne 0 is TRUE"

Can you run the code with options mprint mlogic symbolgen;

Comment: I got the same thing but no email trigger

Answer (score 0):

The `filename` statement should be before a `data step`. Try this.

```
options emailsys=smtp;
%macro sendmail;
    filename mailbox EMAIL 'abc@gmail.com';
    data _null_;
        file mailbox;
%if &syserr ne 0 %then %do;
        put '!em_subject! "Failed"';
        put "Data already avaialable. Please submit for different";
%end;
%else %do; 
        put '!em_subject! "Success"';
        put "Data created"; 
%end;
    run; 
%mend sendmail;
%sendmail
```